# How to send parameters to a webservice method that only accepts one argument in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I am new to webservices in general. I am trying to add 4 parameters to the rmc service CreateCar, and have attempted to do so in my Webservices.cs file. Unfortunately, the CreateCar method only takes 1 argument (request). Most of this code is based on similar processes that do accept all the parameters.

The call I am trying to make is the rmcService.CreateCar.

```
    public bool CreateCar(string url, string viewedUserType, string userName, string accounts, string carName)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;

        try
        {
            if (accounts.Length != 9)
            {
                if (accounts.Length == 8)
                {
                    accounts = accounts + "0";
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Invalid length for Account #");
                }
            }

            // Initialize web service object
            relationshipmgmtcentersvcdev.RmcService rmcService = new relationshipmgmtcentersvcdev.RmcService();
            rmcService.Url = url;

            // Attach credentials
            rmcService.Credentials = _Credentials;

            // Connection pooling
            rmcService.ConnectionGroupName = _Credentials.UserName.ToString();
            rmcService.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;

            // Hard coding View User Type as None
            viewedUserType = "None";

            // Call to create CAR - Client Account Relation
            rmcService.CreateCar(userName, viewedUserType, accounts, carName); 
            returnValue = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Application");
            eventLog.Source = "UAccCompWrapper";
            eventLog.WriteEntry("Error in CreateCar Method: " + ex.ToString(), System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

The error I receive is no overload for method CreateCar takes 4 arguments (which makes sense). I was just trying to illustrate what I was trying to do. This method only takes 1 argument it seems.

This is a snippet of the reference file with the information I found was relevant. It appears that I need to create a BaseServiceRequest with the parameters, but I am unsure how.

```
  /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://relationshipmgmtcenter.hfg.com/services/IRmcService/CreateCar", RequestNamespace="http://relationshipmgmtcenter.hfg.com/services/", ResponseNamespace="http://relationshipmgmtcenter.hfg.com/services/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public void CreateCar([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)] CreateCarServiceRequest request) {
        this.Invoke("CreateCar", new object[] {
                    request});
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void CreateCarAsync(CreateCarServiceRequest request) {
        this.CreateCarAsync(request, null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void CreateCarAsync(CreateCarServiceRequest request, object userState) {
        if ((this.CreateCarOperationCompleted == null)) {
            this.CreateCarOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnCreateCarOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("CreateCar", new object[] {
                    request}, this.CreateCarOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OnCreateCarOperationCompleted(object arg) {
        if ((this.CreateCarCompleted != null)) {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.CreateCarCompleted(this, new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }


/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(UserProfileServiceRequest))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(RenameGroupServiceRequest))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(CreateCarServiceRequest))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(DeleteGroupServiceRequest))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(GetMgrServiceRequest))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HF.Rmc.Service.Library.Requests")]
public partial class BaseServiceRequest {

    private string sessionIdField;

    private string userNameField;

    private string viewedUserField;

    private ViewedUserType viewedUserTypeField;

    private bool viewedUserTypeFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string SessionId {
        get {
            return this.sessionIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.sessionIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string UserName {
        get {
            return this.userNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.userNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string ViewedUser {
        get {
            return this.viewedUserField;
        }
        set {
            this.viewedUserField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ViewedUserType ViewedUserType {
        get {
            return this.viewedUserTypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.viewedUserTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool ViewedUserTypeSpecified {
        get {
            return this.viewedUserTypeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.viewedUserTypeFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}


public partial class CreateCarServiceRequest : BaseServiceRequest {

    private string accountsField;

    private string carNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string Accounts {
        get {
            return this.accountsField;
        }
        set {
            this.accountsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string CarName {
        get {
            return this.carNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.carNameField = value;
        }
    }
} 
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "4.0.30319.18408")]
public delegate void CreateCarCompletedEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e);
```

Comment: Is this asmx or svc?

Comment: At first glance ...use an new instance of "CreateCarServiceRequest" class as parameter....
But think that: you can't change the server behavior changing only the proxy.

Comment: This is svc. The code I wrote was based on similar asmx processes.

Comment: FYI, this client was created via "Add Web Reference". That uses the legacy ASMX technology, even if the service itself is a WCF service. Use "Add Service Reference" instead.

Comment: You can send a CSV string and then split the string in the service.  You can also serialize the data to XML and send the XML string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
rmcService.CreateCar(new CreateCarServiceRequest
                    {
                        UserName = userName,
                        ViewedUserType = Enum.Parse(typeof(ViewedUserType), viewedUserType)
                        Accounts = accounts,
                        CarName = carName
                    });
```

Comment: Just attempted this and got the error "The type or namespace name 'CreateCarServiceRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I got the same error with ViewedUserType...

Comment: Hmmm, it's silly, but i think that you just should add using derective with namespace where CreateCarServiceRequest exists.

Look for namespace keyword in the file with CreateCarServiceRequest.